# What does the '#' symbol mean in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml

I was reading Algorithms in a Nutshell (O'Reilly) and came across this symbol in a class diagram.  My guess is that it means the member is protected, but I wanted to see if anyone knows for sure what it means.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

It indicates a protected *member* of a class or other data type.

`-` Indicates private

`+` Indicates public

`#` Indicates protected

Comment: The visibility indicator can apply to association ends as well as attributes and operations.

Comment: I've seen some UML diagrams define `f` for final (functions that cannot be overriden), `underline` or `s` for static functions, and `italics` or `a` for abstract functions.

Comment: What if you dont want a modifier/symbol ? Just leave it blank?

Comment: @vipin8169 Yes. However, the default accessibility modifier is language-specific. For example, in Visual Basic, it's `public`, whereas it's `internal` in C#. If your diagram doesn't make it otherwise clear what the default accessibility modifier is, it's a good practice to include the access modifier symbol.

Answer (score 14):

Add also to :

~ Indicates package-private (or default)

Answer (score 8):

'#' indicates the visibility. In this case it refers to a protected operation [ edited out the term 'method' as this is not as generic ].

Comment: PS: The reference to look this up is UML 2.0 In A Nutshell. A desktop quick reference. Dan Pilone, Niel Pitman. O'Reilly.

Comment: Oh yes, my terminology isn't accurate. A bit sloppy. The below post by Mike Hofer uses the term 'protected member'. I think if you want to be completely accurate / agnostic, you could say a 'protected operation'.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be snarky, and I apologize if it seemed I was. Truth is, the symbol can be applied to attributes as well as operations, so its scope is a bit broader, and I wanted to be sure that was clear. Again, my apologies for seeming crass: it was not my intent.

Answer (score 4):

'#' stands for visibility "protected" (similar to public,private ) behavior of the property/methods in the class . You can find more of the same at [uml_basic_notations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_basic_notations.htm)

Answer (score 3):

It implies that it is protected, for a variable it will only be seen in the class and inherited classes.